# If we have two TMs D1 and D2 and the languages of the TMs L(D1) != L(D2), then is this problem decidable/recognizable?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, undecidability

We know that in the case where, L(D1) = L(D2), the problem is undecidable. But what happens when the languages are not equal?

I would assume it's still undecidable, but is it recognizable? And how would we build a recognizer for it?

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking.  "the problem", "this problem" - what problem?  We expect you to specify the problem clearly.  A useful way to do that is to specify the language of YES instances, or specify it in terms of the inputs to the algorithm and the desired output.